# Check For get_post_meta on Author Archive Page

Tags: post-meta, user-meta, author, author-template

I've had a good look thru the Similar Questions for an answer and i'm looking to check if a value for a custom field key on single posts has been added using `get_post_meta();` however i want to use this check on the author archive page.

This is my code in functions.php

```
global $wp_query;

$post = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

$meta  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key', true );

if ( $meta ) :
```

**Update :** This function doesn't work on the author archive page.

```
function author_has_name() {
global $post;
$name = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'author_name', true);
return !empty($name);
}
```

However, the code won't work in the author.php template

Comment: Are you trying to get meta-data from the user or from a post? On author.php global $wp_query would point to the author being viewed. `$post->ID` would be for a user which would use [get_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/). What action/filter are you using? Could you provide more context?

Comment: I'm using get_post_meta on the single post edit page to add data for the author but i need to check it has been added before i show it on the author archive, The data is basic author name, description etc using custom keys with get post meta so i assume it won't work with get user meta.

Comment: If adding as post-meta then it won't be specific to the author because it's post-id specific. If looping post on author page don't use `global $wp_query` just use get_the_id() while in the loop of posts which you want post-meta from. Or add as user-meta, there's comment-meta too you can work with.

Comment: It's outside the loop and the post meta is used with the author filter. I'll add to code to a update.